# using javascript in flutter

Tags: javascript, flutter, charts

I'm looking for a half donut chart with round border in flutter but I didn't find.
I found one in amCharts website which is written in javascript in below link:

"https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/WMqWZL"

is there any way to use it from javascript as a widget in flutter?

Comment: Can you try this, it's not javascript but it help you to achieve what you expect. https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/gallery.html

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, but the problem is this package that it isn't flexible enough to allow me changing the border radius of the sections and add text label over them which are required by my design.

Comment: @flutter_dev_89 did you find any solution for this problem. I am stuck in the same situation